# iPhone Restore process

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, restore, storage

Have taken the back up of iphone to replace the battery of phone.  After replacing battery, need to restore the phone back. The iPhone back is stored at default location.  iPhone backup size is 114 GB. Computer – Windows 7, Free space on computer 40GB.

While restoring the iphone, itunes initiate the process however, after some times gives message due to error, restoring process is stopped.  There is no other message or information in itunes.  However, computer gives message that running low on disk space.

Noticed that iTunes is creating the directory at same location with same name but addition the date and time stamp, on drive and when it is not able to write anymore as hard drive is filled up, it stops the restore process.

Called the Apple support and they are advising that itunes will create the back up of back up, effectively needing the more than double the memory size on disk than size of your iphone.

Need to know

1. Can we change the location from where itunes will read the backup data? If yes, I can transfer the backup file to other drive and keep there to read it for itunes. itunes can write the data at new default location as it will have enough space once back up is moved to new location.
2. Can we change the location to where iTunes will create the temporary files?  If yes, I can leave the back up files at original location but ask itunes to create tempoeraty directory to another location. itunes can write the temporary data to another location and then delete it.

I can find the solution on web to change the backup location using the windows command but nothing for restoration process.

Anyone else with same problems?  With newer devices coming with higher capacity, this problem should come to everyone eventually.

Comment: "Don't edit, relocate, rename, or extract content from your backup files, because these actions might ruin the files. For example, to restore from a relocated backup file, you need to move it back or the file won't work." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215#findiTunes relocation seems to be ruled out. : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300776/how-do-i-restore-an-iphone-from-a-backup-located-on-an-external-drive?rq=1